# Can someone please explain the meaning of following code in plsql?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Could Someone please explain the meaning of below code in plsql?

```
date BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE-6, 'iw') AND TRUNC(SYSDATE-6, 'iw')+6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to actually select those values and see what they represent.

Setting environment, to know *what is what*:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.
```

Right now is:

```
SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
-------------------
05.04.2023 21:34:57
```

First part of that period: subtract 6 days from "right now" (which is 30.03.2023) and truncate it to the first day of *week of year* (the `iw` format model), based on ISO standard:

```
SQL> select TRUNC(SYSDATE-6, 'iw') from dual;

TRUNC(SYSDATE-6,'IW
-------------------
27.03.2023 00:00:00    --> Monday
```

Second part of that period: just the same as previously (so you get 27.03.2023) and then **add** 6 days to it:

```
SQL> select TRUNC(SYSDATE-6, 'iw')+6 from dual;

TRUNC(SYSDATE-6,'IW
-------------------
02.04.2023 00:00:00    --> Sunday

SQL>
```

Comment: For questions involving `between` on `date` datatype in Oracle it's worth to add that `date` is a misleading name for `datetime` and it **always** store hours, minutes and seconds. To select *days* between two dates we use `date_col >= trunc(date_start) and date_col < trunc(date_end) + 1` to include a zero second of the first day and the last second of the last day. `between` will filter out everything after the start of the `end_date`.

Answer (score 0):

The query includes a condition on the `date` field using the `BETWEEN` operator, which specifies a range of values for the field. The range is defined by two expressions separated by the `AND` operator.

The first expression is `TRUNC(SYSDATE-6, 'iw')`, which uses the `TRUNC` function to round down the date value of six days ago to the nearest beginning of the ISO week. This means that it returns the date of the Monday of the week six days ago.

The second expression is `TRUNC(SYSDATE-6, 'iw')+6`, which adds six days to the first expression, resulting in the date of the Sunday of the same week.

Taken together, the `BETWEEN` condition specifies that the `date` field must fall within the range of the Monday six days go and the Sunday of the same week.

In summary, this psql code selects data with a `date` field that falls within a specific range of dates, namely the week that was six days ago from today, from Monday to Sunday.